My pendrive is not visible in any pc
I'm trying to remove BitLocker from my pendrive, when this process is going on sudden power outage occurred my system suddenly shutdown and when I open the pc again the pendrive was not detected and when I try to connect it with another pc it also wasn’t detected.

Most certainly, any data on the drive is gone. However, if you open Disk Management on Windows, and you see the drive listed at all, it can possibly be cleared and reused.

Press Windows and type diskmg.
Select diskmgmt.msc.
Select the USB flash drive. Be careful, a mistake can destroy another drive!
Right-click it and select Delete volume.*
In the menu, select View | Top | Disk list.
In the bottom pane, select Removable... with unallocated space.
Right-click, and select New Simple Volume.
Follow the Wizard to create and format the volume. For most USB drive use, FAT32 is preferred to NTFS.

